# Display auto incremented id while adding or uploading a document

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am a beginner in Sharepoint. I have a list with column name EmpId and it should get incremented automatically when a new item is added to the list.
Along with this when the user clicks on Add/Upload New Document this EmpId should get displayed by default on the edit page where user will enter rest of the fields manually.
Can you help me out with every detailed step.

Comment: In SharePoint for every list or library there exists a hidden system field/column named "ID" which is auto-incremented.. If you are not aware of it, you can use that instead..

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned before, you can use system field ID as an auto incremented field in the form. However, it is hidden by default. According to [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpI09.png), you can get the item id from the URL, but script from this link does not work with document library, because its form doesn't have attachments block. I changed that script to make it more fluent, look at the example below:

1. Open edit form link with additional parameter ToolPaneView. Something like this /Documents/Forms/EditForm.aspx?ID=1&ToolPaneView=2
2. Add content editor web part to the form 
   [image]
3. Click on the Content editor and from the ribbon panel open HTML Source Editor
   [image]
4. Pass the code example below

   ```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

   _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("showID");

   function GetUrlParam(name) {
      var url = location.search.toLowerCase();
      var n = name.toLowerCase();
      return decodeURI((RegExp(n + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(url) || [, null])[1]);
   }

   function showID()
   {
           var id = GetUrlParam("id");
           $("table.ms-formtable > tbody").prepend($(String.format("<tr><td class='ms-formlabel'>Item ID</td><td class='ms-formbody'>{0}</td></tr>",id)));
   }

   </script>
   ```

Should look something like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint Lists automatically have an column with "ID" which auto increments. You simply need to select this column from the "modify view" screen to view it.

If you wanted unique IDs like CUST1, CUST2, ... it might be possible to create a Calculated column and use the value of the ID column in you formula (="CUST" & [ID]).

Answer (score 0):

As Arsalan has indicated, the ID field will automatically increment with each item added to the list.  However, note that this is not allocated until the item is saved so will not be visible or even available when the user is completing the Add New Item form.

When I have done this in the past, I have often needed to have the unique ID in a particular format - eg EMP001, EMP002 etc.  If you try to do this with a calculated column you may find the results to be inconsistent as the column is calculated before the ID is allocated.  However this is fine if you later edit an item.  The best option is probably a workflow which triggers when an item is created and constructs the EmpID in the format you require using the ID field and writes this value back to the list item.  The workflow is triggered after the item is added to the list so the ID is available - it just means there is a very slight delay before you will actually see the EmpID field populated.

Hope this helps.